Media Player created with python 3- Problem
This code create media player with python 3.10, but the problem is that when media video file uploaded the a-b loop and media speed changer buttons doesn't work:
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer

kivy.require('2.0.0')

class MediaPlayer(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'

        self.video = VideoPlayer(source='', state='stop')
        self.add_widget(self.video)

        self.controls = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=None, height='50dp')
        self.add_widget(self.controls)

        self.play_button = Button(text='Play/Pause')
        self.play_button.bind(on_press=self.toggle_play)
        self.controls.add_widget(self.play_button)

        self.a_button = Button(text='Set A')
        self.a_button.bind(on_press=self.set_a)
        self.controls.add_widget(self.a_button)

        self.b_button = Button(text='Set B')
        self.b_button.bind(on_press=self.set_b)
        self.controls.add_widget(self.b_button)

        self.loop_button = Button(text='Toggle Loop')
        self.loop_button.bind(on_press=self.toggle_loop)
        self.controls.add_widget(self.loop_button)

        self.speed_label = Label(text='Speed:')
        self.controls.add_widget(self.speed_label)

        self.speed_slider = Slider(min=0.4, max=1.2, value=1.0)
        self.speed_slider.bind(value=self.set_speed)
        self.controls.add_widget(self.speed_slider)

        self.browse_button = Button(text='Browse')
        self.browse_button.bind(on_press=self.browse_file)
        self.controls.add_widget(self.browse_button)

        self.a_time = None
        self.b_time = None
        self.loop_enabled = False

    def toggle_play(self, instance):
        if self.video.state == 'play':
            self.video.state = 'pause'
        else:
            self.video.state = 'play'

    def set_a(self, instance):
        self.a_time = self.video.position
        print(f'Set A at {self.a_time}')

    def set_b(self, instance):
        self.b_time = self.video.position
        print(f'Set B at {self.b_time}')

    def toggle_loop(self, instance):
        self.loop_enabled = not self.loop_enabled
        print(f'Loop enabled: {self.loop_enabled}')

    def set_speed(self, instance, value):
        self.video.playback_rate = value

    def browse_file(self, instance):
        content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        filechooser = FileChooserListView()
        content.add_widget(filechooser)

        select_button = Button(text='Select')
        content.add_widget(select_button)

        popup = Popup(title='Select a video file', content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))

        def on_file_select(instance):
            if filechooser.selection:
                self.video.source = filechooser.selection[0]
                self.video.state = 'play'
                popup.dismiss()

        select_button.bind(on_press=on_file_select)
        popup.open()

    def on_update(self, dt):
        if self.loop_enabled and self.a_time is not None and self.b_time is not None:
            if self.video.position > self.b_time or self.video.position < self.a_time:
                self.video.position = self.a_time

class MediaPlayerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        player = MediaPlayer()
        kivy.clock.Clock.schedule_interval(player.on_update, 1 / 30.0)
        return player

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MediaPlayerApp().run()

I also need that this media player will read the most video file formats. when i run the code it open the window of the player and it run the video file but without the option of using the buttons i mention before.

So, does the toggle_play function run when you click your "Play/Pause" button? I mean can you confirm (yes/no) about if the video state changes when the button is clicked?

i will check, thank you for the advice

when i click on "set a" button python write : Set A at 143.42442709067836    then i click on "set b" button python write :    Set B at 145.4246756. now when i click on "Toggle Loop" python write: Loop enabled: True   but the loop don't activate
